# A weird use of "could have" in a non-hypothetical situation

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, could

I saw a sentence in a book that I am reading now. That seems very weird to me and I need clarification.

> All this happened between sunrise and sunset, the boy thought. He was feeling sorry for himself, and lamenting the fact that his life could have changed so suddenly and so drastically."

In storyline, his life definitely has changed. So, its no use using the "could have" here. I mean, it would be okay if it says "have changed" instead putting "could".

Is this a grammatical error? Or there is something that I do not know?

*The sentence is from The Alchemist, Paulo Coelho and the translation is the work of Alan R. Clarke, published by HarperOne.*

Comment: Quoting from a book does not violate copyright. It would be good for us to have the exact sentence and its source so that we understand the context.

Comment: related - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/588580/could-have-past-participle-in-questions Pondered invokes questioning. This is a covert question with the auxiliary *could* not expressing an unreal condition.  It means *Elma was pondering how the course of her life could have changed instantly.*

Comment: As @alphabet said, we need more context (a lot more). At the very least, tell us the book you’re reading.

Comment: Also, I am wondering if you are reading a translation. Something like this is perfectly natural: *Elma wondered how the course of her life could have changed instantly.*

Comment: It's not used so well, but *fact* is a key word here. Elma is flabbergasted by the mere fact…that her life is a big ball of uncertainty like everyone else's. Or so it seems.

Comment: I edited the question. Please, reconsider your evaluations.

Comment: This is just the past tense of can have changed. Elma is pondering the fact of how the course of her life can have changed instantly.

Comment: I turned down this translation because I read the book, the setting is in the Middle Ages or Renaissance and the author has plastic curtains in it. Among other things. But yes, if he was lamenting it, it **did happen**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> British Council English:
>
> **can't have / couldn't have**
> **We use can't have and couldn't have + past participle when we think it's not possible that something happened.**
>
> She **can't have driven** there. Her car keys are still here.

> I thought I saw Adnan this morning but it **couldn't have been him**  –
> he's in Greece this week.

[modals + deductions about the past](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/modals-deductions-about-past)

> Elma was pondering the fact that the course of her life could have
> changed instantly. **Past tense due to "was pondering"**
>
> Elma is pondering the fact that the course of her life can have
> changed instantly. **Present tense due to "is pondering"**.

*could have changed* there means: *actually did change*. It means "how was it possible that x could have happened". In this case, it does not mean it didn't happen.

"How could you have done this terrible thing?" Meaning: You did do it.

So can have/could have + past participle can also be declarative and not negative, like in the sample. And the situation may or may not have happened. Only context will tell us that.

Of course, **grammatically one can say**:

> Elma was pondering the fact that the course of her life **had**
> changed OR changed instantly. However, the present perfect does not work here as the main verb is in the past. is pondering/has changed and was pondering/had changed.

But that was not the author's intention in the sample sentence.
She was pondering the possibility that her life had in fact changed.

Declarative: could have, should have, would have, all + past participle

This use of "could" is not a conditional like this:

- I could go, if I wanted to.
- How *could he have gone* to London without me? [He did go, in fact]
  Meaning: How was it possible that he went to London without me? But it can also mean the person is questioning that.
- How could he have seen her if she was here? [This implies: He didn't see her, in fact]
  But **it can also imply**:
- How was it possible he saw her if she was here.

Comment: This clarified everything. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> Or there is something that I do not know?

Yes: "**could** is the past tense of "**can**" -> to be able to

> "All this happened between sunrise and sunset, the boy thought. He was feeling sorry for himself, and lamenting the fact that his life **was able to** have changed so suddenly and so drastically."

Comment: Do you mean the sentence implies here only the flexible ability of the change in the past and not talking about any hypothetical situation? If it is that, I guess I get it.

Comment: You can also see it as "it **was possible** for his life to have changed so suddenly".

Comment: was able to have changed? Don't think so....A person was able to x but not a life...

Answer (score 0):

In that context, I would read it that she was not contemplating the exact change she had undergone.  If she were to do that, it would indeed be "had changed" -- not "have changed," since she would be, in the past, contemplating something further in the past.  However, she is not.

Instead, she is contemplating how her life, which had seemed steady, secure, and unchangeable, of which she would have said that it could not change, did indeed surprise her by changing.  How could that have happened?

Comment: As I said, the change has definitely occurred. I mean, the girl started an adventure in the morning and get lost afternoon. The sentence was put in the afternoon as the girl was very upset. She was wishing to be back in the other sentence.

Comment: That is, she was not upset by the *particulars* of the change, but that it had happened at all.  That is why she is contemplating that change occurred.

Comment: Thanks. I added the exact sentence. So maybe you want to check it.

Comment: Yes.  In fact I would be more certain of this interpretation for the actual sentence.